# US travel restrictions on arrivals - does this apply to stopovers?

Tags: usa, transit, ireland

I see that there is a Presidential Proclamation that restricts aliens from entering the United States if they have been physically present in Ireland (along with some other countries) any time over the past 14 days. Now, I am looking at a flight to the US that has a technical stopover in Dublin, where I do not have to deplane. I know even transiting through an airport is restricted, but what about this situation?

The airline has told me that a stopover is not an issue and that they have had passengers who have entered the US with no issue. However, I guess I am just paranoid and do not want to be sent back at the border.

Comment: Will new people enter the plane at your stop?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I suppose you think that would be the issue?

Comment: @Arthur Contact the handling agent at the departure airport, as they decide whether you get onboard or not. Due to the US being very strict, they'll only let you board if being 100% sure you'll be able to enter (possibly consulting with the CBP in case of any doubt), so if they let you board, you're unlikely to be sent back on this basis

Comment: I suppose you mean a technical stop, not a stopover? A stopover is a break in the itinerary, where you get off the plane, reclaim your luggage, exit the airport, and later (usually >24 hours later) you check-in again. Can you clarify what flight this is? It **may** make a difference if it's a technical stop (just to refuel, usually), and you are kept segregated from other passengers or if it's an actual stop where people can disembark or more importantly, join the flight at that airport.

Comment: Well it is a stopover rather than a layover, meaning that I will remain on the plane rather than get off the plane. However, I do believe there will be people joining the flight at that airport.

Comment: @Arthur that would be a _stop_ (if people can leave or join) or a _technical stop_ (if people don't, usually just for refuelling purposes). A _stopover_ is a long layover where you leave the plane and even the airport.

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned the airline involved.  Dublin is an interesting situation as it is a US Pre-clearance location, so some flights have passengers clear US immigration in Dublin.  It sounds like you believe this isn't the case, but  knowing the airline would confirm that one way or the other.

Comment: It's Ethiopian Airlines.

Comment: Also, the airline has clarified that this will be a technical stop with no passengers boarding in Dublin. I double checked by looking for Ethiopian Airlines flights from Dublin to Dulles and indeed there aren't any. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 2):

As no passengers can board the plane in Ireland, the stop there should not impact whether you can enter the USA.

So you should be able to trust the airline and go with their advice.